# Как вывести число 123456 так 123.456 в php?

Tags: php

Собственно вопрос в заголовке, например мне число `123456789`
нужно вывести как `123.456.789`
Или другой пример `11000000000`
вывести как `11.000.000.000`.
В php не гуру, поэтому обращаюсь к вам.
*Как такое реализовать?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию `number_format`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Comment: Нет, когда я использую эту функцию, вывожу переменную, а она пустая, ну нечего не выводится

Comment: @Yellow показывайте код

Comment: Вот https://pastebin.com/d8RSb5PN

Comment: намдер и намбер - это разные переменные

Comment: Ага, я исправил. НО теперь вывелось моё число, в конец которого добавлено ,00

Comment: Потому что надо так `number_format($number, 0, false, '.');`

Comment: А всё, спасибо. Это я ошибся, забыл пробел поставить